# What does \ do in python?

Tags: python

I'm looking at someone's code on AI but I don't quite understand what the `\` is doing in the first line of the function definition. Can someone explain? I know `\` is a special operator when paired with `n` or `t` to give new line or tab but I'm not sure if in this case it's just `\` or `\.`. If so what is it doing?

```
@staticmethod        
def get_next(target_net, next_states):                
    final_state_locations = next_states.flatten(start_dim=1) \
        .max(dim=1)[0].eq(0).type(torch.bool)
    non_final_state_locations = (final_state_locations == False)
    non_final_states = next_states[non_final_state_locations]
    batch_size = next_states.shape[0]
    values = torch.zeros(batch_size).to(QValues.device)
    values[non_final_state_locations] = target_net(non_final_states).max(dim=1)[0].detach()
    return values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It separates lines, in PEP8 the maximum length of a line is 79 characters.

```
print('Hello world!')
```

is the same as:

```
print \
('Hello world!')
```